# Remove route google maps API using button

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can draw route using coordinates.

I'm trying to delete the road when I press clear, but it does not work.

Below the function I execute when pressing the button "Clear map".

```js
function Clear() {
 alert(directionsDisplay.length);
    // MyArray = [];
 directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
 document.getElementById("Coords").value = "";
 document.getElementById("Coords").disabled = false;
 document.getElementById("btnAdd").disabled = false;

}
```

Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/129/).

Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error on your page when I click the "Clear Map" button: `Uncaught TypeError: directionsDisplay.setMap is not a function` on this line:

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
```

Because directionsDisplay is an array (`var directionsDisplay = [];`), and doesn't have a `setMap` method.  That line should be at a minimum (assuming you only want this to work once):

```
directionsDisplay[0].setMap(null);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/147/)

Comment: Thakns for your reply.
Actually, When i clair the map I cannot draw another route on it. is it normal ?

Comment: Nope.  That is another error in your code (I can draw another route in my fiddle, but there are issues)..

Comment: It is ok ! It works. I'm wandering if there is a way to remove the text below the map after pressing clear button ?

Comment: Clear the `directions_panel` div (`document.getElementById("directions_panel").innerHTML = "";`) if you want that text to go away, updated the fiddle.